# React, accessing the DOM with gelElementById, then trying to replace a node with a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

If I want to substitute a DOM node with a ReactJS node, how can I do it?

```
const myComp = <span>hey</span>
const elem = document.getElementById('video1')
elem.parentNode.replaceChild(myComp, elem)
```

What's the way to do it? This doesn't work

```
var temp = document.createElement('div')
ReactDOM.render(myComp, temp)
console.log(temp) // a node with the nested div element
console.log(temp.firstChild) // null (??)
console.log(temp.firstElementChild) // null (??)
elem.parentNode.replaceChild(temp.firstElementChild, elem) // error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const elem = document.getElementById('video1') 

...    

ReactDOM.render(myComp, elem)
```